# Sveltekit relative anchor tag href based on the folder

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have the following folder structure

```
-> routes
    '-> blog
         |-> __layout.svelte
         |-> blogs.svelte
         '-> new.svelte
```

At this moment in `__layout.svelte` I have to hardcode the full URL,

```
            <a href="/blog/blogs>All Blogs</a>
            <a href="/blog/new>Create New Blog</a>
```

I want the ability to remove hard coding the `/blog` in the href as if I move from `blog` to `posts` I have to change all URLs. So something like

```
           <a href="{folder}/blogs">All Blogs</a>
```

is it possible?

Comment: sveltekit, doesnt support that now. And as sveltekit is an SSR version it wont include this as feature in near future. Or you can use `svelte-spa-router` third party library which supports your requirements https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router/blob/master/Advanced%20Usage.md#nested-routers

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, but you have to define `{folder}` somewhere (otherwise Svelte would not know which folder you are referring too).

This can be as easy as create a file `/lib/paths.js` with

```js
export const POSTS = '/blog';
```

and then where you need it

```html
<script>
 import {POSTS} from '$lib/paths';
</script>

<a href="{POSTS}/blog">All blogs</a>
```

of course you have to remember to update these constants.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

You can make the blogfolder a dynamic slug [(more information)](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-pages). The advantage of this way of working compared to Stephans answer is that you don't need to change your project on 2 places when you decide to change the name of your route. You only have to change the variable in you code and not your folder structure

**How does that look like?**

```
-> routes
'-> [folderName]
     |-> __layout.svelte
     |-> blogs.svelte
     '-> new.svelte
```

You can then reach the blogs.svelte page by using both "/blog/blogs.svelte" or "/topics/blogs.svelte".

If you want to compile your pages statically afterwards, make sure to have an explicit link to the blogs pages or include the correct link in the command line while compiling.